# Remove callback for handler not work

Tags: android, handler

I have written a handler that calls the method every time interval. I want to remove that handler in on destroy(). The code i use as follows, In Oncreate()

```
private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
public int DATA_INTERVAL = 30 * 1000;
Runnable getData;
 getData = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                     recieveData();
            }
        };

 _handler.postDelayed(getData, DATA_INTERVAL);
```

and in ondestroy(), i use,

```
_handler.removeCallbacks(getData);
```

But removecallbacks not work. It calls after exiting the activity.

Comment: You could call `_handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages()` without any parameter. It removes everything in the callbacks and messages stack

Comment: @Kor it gives error when calling _handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages() without parameter.

Comment: _handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) use this line and let me know if it works.

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callback-from-a-handler

Comment: @Raghav thanks. but its works now by using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844308/removecallbacks-not-stopping-runnable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[removeCallbacks(Runnable r)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

so `removeCallbacks(..)` only stops pending messages (Runnables) not currently running runnable so if you want to stop currently running Runable then use a Boolean varaible for Stoping Thread when user Exit from your app.

see this post for [removeCallbacks not stopping runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844308/removecallbacks-not-stopping-runnable)

Comment: Wrong. Notice he's calling `removeCallbacks` from `onDestroy` which runs in the main thread. So either a pending Runnable runs first and then `onDestroy` cancels all future callbacks, or `onDestroy` runs first and cancels all future callbacks so no Runnable would run after that. He has a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the most important part of the code which is the `receiveData` method. As you said you are running the task periodically, you must be calling again `postDelayed` from inside that method to reschedule the task. Probably background threads involved as you cannot do networking on the main thread.

You most likely have a race condition when exiting the Activity. `onDestroy` runs first and then the task is posted again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Then all handler callbacks will removed.