# Stop vibrating onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity, android-vibration

I have an activity that vibrates the phone for 9 seconds after it starts.  I want the vibration action to be canceled when the activity leaves the foreground. Here is my current code:

```
     Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // change image
             screen.setImageResource(R.drawable.yama);

             vibrateMe();
        }
    }, 9000);



        }


public void vibrateMe() {


    Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    vibrate.vibrate(2000);
}


public void stopVibrating(Vibrator vibrate) {

    vibrate.cancel();
}

@Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


}

}
```

Comment: If you want to stop when the user leaves your Activity, you want to override `onPause()` instead; `onDestroy()` might not necessarily be called. I still don't see what the problem is though.

Comment: when i leave the app the phone still vibrates after 9 seconds !
This is the problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to cancel your runnable? 
There are 2 options:

- you can cancel all your delayed runnables with [handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callback-from-a-handler)
- you should save ref to runnable (Runnable vibrateRunnable = new Runnable() ... ) and then remove it if needed with [handler.removeCallbacks(vibrateRunnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel all CallBacks and Messages using removeCallbacksAndMessages();

```
public final void removeCallbacksAndMessages (Object token)
```

Added in API level 1
Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.