# MediaPlayer NullPointerException after OnBackPressed Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, onpause

if I click the Back Button in PoiView class I get a NullPointer Exception. The parent activity is loaded, but then the error is thrown. Before I click the back button I´ve played a file in the mediaplayer, but paused before using the back button.

Hase anyone a hint, how I can solve this NullPointer? The problem is the following:

```
startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
```

It seems, that no value is available to fill this textView?

PoiView class:

```
public class PoiView extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<RowItem> pois;
    Integer citySave;
    String cityTitle;
    Integer routeSave;
    String routeTitel;
    String poiTitel;
    String poiAudio;
    String poiImage;
    String textPoi;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private double startTime = 0;
    private double finalTime = 0;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
    public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
    public TextView startTimeField,endTimeField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_view);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        pois = b.getParcelableArrayList("pois");
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
        routeTitel = b.getString("titel_route");
        routeSave = b.getInt("route");
        poiTitel = b.getString("titel_poi");
        poiAudio = b.getString("audioPoi");
        poiImage = b.getString("imagePoi");
        textPoi = b.getString("textPoi");

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setTitle(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_poi_view)) + " " + poiTitel);

        TextView titelPoi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namePoi);
        titelPoi.setText(poiTitel);

        ImageView picPoi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePoi);
        picPoi.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(poiImage, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        TextView infotextPoi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPoi);
        infotextPoi.setText(textPoi);

        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);
        pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagePause);
        startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStart);

        seekbar.setClickable(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStop);

        try {
            int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(poiAudio, "raw", getPackageName());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.audioerror);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });

    }

    public void play(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.audio_play,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
            seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
            oneTimeOnly = 1;
        }
        endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                        toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
        );
        startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                        toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
        myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
    }


    private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
            );
            seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    public void pause(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.audio_pause,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mediaPlayer.pause();
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(PoiView.this, RouteView.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        b.putInt("route", routeSave);
        b.putString("titel_route", routeTitel);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Bundle b = new Bundle();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.imagePoi));
        System.gc();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    }

    public class MusicIntentReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        finish();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view)
    {
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.imagePoi));
        System.gc();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poi_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_stadt:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stadt);
                Intent stadt = new Intent(PoiView.this, StadtActivity.class);
                startActivity(stadt);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_route:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
                Intent route = new Intent(PoiView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
                route.putExtra("stadt", citySave);
                route.putExtra("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
                startActivity(route);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_routeview:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_view);
                Intent routeview = new Intent(PoiView.this, RouteView.class);
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                    // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
                    // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
                    routeview.putExtra("stadt", citySave);
                    routeview.putExtra("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
                    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                            // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                                    // Navigate up to the closest parent
                            .startActivities();
                } else {
                    // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
                    // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                    routeview.putExtra("stadt", citySave);
                    routeview.putExtra("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
                }
                routeview.putExtra("route", routeSave);
                routeview.putExtra("titel_route", routeTitel);
                startActivity(routeview);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
                Intent help = new Intent(PoiView.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(help);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    08-07 12:31:34.054    4602-4602/de.cityknight.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ae2ba8)
08-07 12:31:34.064    4602-4602/de.cityknight.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.cityknight.app, PID: 4602
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at de.cityknight.app.PoiView$2.run(PoiView.java:142)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check if any of the variables is null.

Comment: what´s the best way to do this?

Comment: I think that your log is not complete, can you copy an paste completely the log.

Comment: startTimeField.setText(""+                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime)+
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)); just append "" infront of all the variables to convert it to string

Comment: @user3586222 I´ve added a few more lines, but that´s all, what is marked as error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because your `UpdateSongTime` runnable is still scheduled to run. Call `myHandler.remove callbacks( UpdateSongTime);` before finishing your Activity. P.S. you have a lot of other issues with your code that I won't go in to right this moment.

Comment: Thanks, how can place this handler? Have you got any good reference for inserting a mediaplayer the right way? If you may tell me, what other issues you were investigating, it would be nice.

Comment: I figured it out - that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callback-from-a-handler
If you can name other issues please I could search for it, thanks!

Comment: You should mark answer as correct so other people get the benefit.

Comment: Yea. I was replying whilst you did that.

Comment: OK, if you´ve got the time it would be great to read the other issues. I will try to solve these on my own.