# How to send toast when user is in a specific area?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a working app that posts a toast when the user is in a predefined distance from a point on the map.

To recieve my distance from the user location and the point I've used

```
final float result[] = new float[2];
Location.distanceBetween(prevJoblatlng.latitude, prevJoblatlng.longitude, myLocationMarker.getPosition().latitude, myLocationMarker.getPosition().longitude, result);
```

And in the `onLocationChanged` function I've used a handler to post every ten seconds.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (result[0] <= circle.getRadius()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're nearby a task.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, 10000);
```

However this is working somehow but when the user is out of the are the Handler is still in queue and sends toasts. 
How do I stop the Handler once I am beyond the distance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callback-from-a-handler

Comment: By all the lines of codes, was just fumbling with the docs and found this exact solution. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```