# How to safely stop a handler?

Tags: java, android

I have a handler in android defined as this :

```
myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                switch (msg.what){

                    case 1:

                        break;

                    case 5:

                        break;

                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        };
```

Now what is the best way to kill clear this ? Should I use something as they do here: [handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883635/how-to-remove-all-callbacks-from-a-handler/5884027) Is it better to do in in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not stop a Runnable. You can just stop receiving Callbacks like this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new
                Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);

// use this when you don't want callback to be called anymore
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: I am not using "handler.post(runnable);" in my code.. Should I?  I am just sending messages from threads to the handlers